# Mathematical Modeling Question concerning 2-gender interactions

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I was revising for my Math Modelling term paper, and was doing this particular question in a textbook, where I got stuck for a whole day. Here's a snippet:

[Q1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4vvy.png) 
Reference: Topics in Mathematical Modeling by K.K Tung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

For part a), for individual subpopulation equilibrium, you need: $\displaystyle \frac{dm}{dt} = \frac{df}{dt} = 0$

That gives you:

$$B_f\frac{m^*f^*}{m^*+f^*} = D_ff^*$$

$$B_m\frac{m^*f^*}{m^*+f^*} = D_mm^*$$

Can you manipulate these to eliminate $f^*$ and $m^*$? Try to get an equation in terms of the birth and death rates alone. That is the required condition.

For the second part, let $\displaystyle \frac mf = k$, i.e. $m = kf$. Rewrite the two differential equations only in terms of $f$ and $k$ (use product rule where needed).

Now set $\displaystyle \frac{dk}{dt} = 0$ to find $k^*$. Remember that for this part, $\displaystyle D_f = D_m = D$.

EDIT: I'd like to have hidden this part under a spoiler tag, but I'm not sure how to do it. If anyone wishes to help me by editing this, please feel free.

To find the equilibrium subpopulations for part a), simplify and rearrange the two equations to:

$$\frac{m^*}{m^*+f^*} = \frac{D_f}{B_f}$$

$$\frac{f^*}{m^*+f^*} = \frac{D_m}{B_m}$$

Now add the two to get:

$$\frac{D_f}{B_f} + \frac{D_m}{B_m} = 1$$

which is the required condition.

For part b), by employing product rule to get $\displaystyle \frac{dm}{dt} = k\frac{df}{dt} + f\frac{dk}{dt}$ and then setting $\displaystyle \frac{dk}{dt} = 0$ when $k = k^*$,

we get:

$$\frac{df}{dt} = B_f\frac{k^*}{k^*+1}f - Df$$

and

$$k^*\frac{df}{dt} = B_m\frac{k^*}{k^*+1}f - k^*Df$$

where $D_m$ and $D_f$ have been collapsed to a single parameter $D$.

Multiply the first equation by $k^*$ and equate to get:

$$k^*B_f\frac{k^*}{k^*+1}f -k^*Df = B_m\frac{k^*}{k^*+1}f - k^*Df$$

which simplifies to give $\displaystyle k^* = \frac{B_m}{B_f}$

Comment: @Chris I changed it to $k$ to avoid confusion. $\frac{m}{f} = k$

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for helping, I will work on it now :)

Comment: Also, you don't have to delete all your typing hard work. You should restore it and format it using MathJax. Just follow the wording of the actual question.

Comment: Alright I will do that after I have solved this :) I have tried to eliminate m* and f* for part a, but I am still stuck. I tried multiplication on both sides, addition and so on, can't seem to get it.

Comment: I have found it already, is it along the lines of (Bf - Df)/Df = Dm/(Bm - Dm)

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure how you're getting that. But I edited my post to show you what I got.

Comment: omg. I really just made my life way worse than it was before, that totally made logical sense, now thank you :)

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I just rearranged your equation, and it's equivalent to mine. You can simplify yours to mine easily. :)

Comment: I just noticed, part a requires me to find a non-trivial equilibrium, does that mean that m and f must both be non-zero?

Comment: @Chris I believe that's implied, but since we're dividing (cancelling) by those quantities, we're taking them as non-zero. :)

Comment: I got m* and f* = BC and AD respectively, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you so much, you've been a life-saver I assure you Deepak :)

Comment: If my m* and f* is wrong, can you kindly advise me again, I'm really at my wits end :(

Comment: I also can't seem to get the suggestion of Product Rule for part b

Comment: Could you clarify what A and C are? I don't think it's possible to determine $m^*$ and $f^*$ in part a). Which is why the exercise said "try to...". Basically, when the condition is met, the system of two equations becomes redundant (it's equivalent to just one equation). As such, *any* nonzero values of $m^*$ and $f^*$ are possible, with only the ratio between them being fixed by the constants. Unless I'm much mistaken, you cannot find definite values for $m^*$ and $f^*$ for the first part.

Comment: By product rule, I meant using $m = kf$ to write $\frac{dm}{dt} = f\frac{dk}{dt} + k\frac{df}{dt}$.

Comment: I chose m* to be Df * Bm and f* to be Mf * Dm

Comment: I understand that product rule application, but I don't see how I can get k(t) alone, with the dk/dt gone.

Comment: For part a) I don't see how you can "choose" those values. For part b), your goal is to rewrite both equations in terms of only $k$ and $f$. Then set $\frac {dk}{dt} = 0$, which occurs when $k = k^*$. Now eliminate everything except $k^*$ and the constants.

Comment: I've edited my answer to work out part b) as well.

Comment: I have to turn in now. Goodnight, and good luck on your term paper. :)

Comment: Thank you :) I'll try my best!

Comment: Hi Deepak, sorry to bother you again, but how would I know that the k* is a stable equilibrium?

Comment: I figured it out :)

Comment: @Chris I'm so glad. My apologies as I've been very tied up, I'm flying off in a few hours. Again, best of luck for your paper! :)